# Recoloring of BufferedImage from Black to Red not working

Tags: java, image-processing, graphics2d, java-2d

I have an Image that I originally created as a VolatileImage.  The original image is black.  I would like under program control, to recolor it as Red.  I convert or take a snapshot of the Volatile Image so I can work with it as a BufferedImage, and attempt to recolor it to Red using a LookUpTable.  However, the code you see below doesn't work.  The Image is still Black.  Could someone point out what is wrong?  I am new to image-processing under Java.  Thanks!

```html
 private void recolorAsRed2(VolatileImage sourceImage)
 {
  short[] red = new short[256];
  short[] green= new short[256];
  short[] blue= new short[256];
  short[] alpha = new short[256];
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
     alpha[i]= 1;
     red[i] = 255;
     green[i]= 0;
     blue[i]= 0;
  }
  
  short[][] data= new short[][] {
    red, green, blue, alpha
  };
  
   BufferedImage dstImage= null;
   LookupTable lookupTable= new ShortLookupTable(0, data);
   LookupOp op= new LookupOp(lookupTable, null);
   dstImage= op.filter(sourceImage.getSnapshot(),  dstImage);
   
   Utilities.toBufferedImage(dstImage); // This actually converts the Image back to being a Volatile Image.  The method name does not reflect what the code is doing.
   
 }
```